# Get data from one column based on another using Python

Tags: python, pandas, xlsx, import-from-excel

I'm trying to get data from column1 of a .xlsx file, when the data I provide matches the data in column2 and column4. I tried using `data[data['column2'] == "aa1"]` but not satisfied with the result. For column4 data, I used `int(raw_input("get data: "))` but that didn't work either.

Sample excel file:

```
column1,column2,column3,column4
aa,aa1,lll,21
bb,aa2,ll,22
```

Required output:

```
aa #when an input of aa1 and 21 is given.
```

PS- The data is in the form of a pandas dataframe.

Comment: how are you loading the `.xslx` file into your python code?

Comment: "but not satisfied with the result" ?

Comment: @dbliss I did    `excel = pd.ExcelFile(file_name)
    df = excel.parse("Sheet1")`

Comment: @AndyHayden It prints the complete row, when I just want data from column1. I tried suffixing with [0], that gave me a keyerror.

Comment: ok, so you're asking how to get data in a `pandas` `DataFrame`.  please edit your question to include this.

Comment: @dbliss Your deleted answer worked fine but how do I tell it to match data from column4 also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want this:

```
data[(data['column2'] == "aa1") & (data['column4'] == 21)]
```

So to use multiple conditions you need to use `&` instead of `and` because we are comparing arrays also you need to use parentheses due to operator precedence